# Java batch (JSR 352) with Weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: weblogic, java-ee-7, jsr352, java-batch

Can i use java batch with weblogic 12.1.3?
This version of weblogic support java EE 7 but in the console I can not find a page with the Batch configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use Batch API (JSR 352) with 12.1.3 version of Weblogic as this version is not a full Java EE 7 version.

It's a Java EE 6 version with few Java EE 7 API in advance : `JAX-RS 2.0 (JSR 339)`, `WebSocket API (JSR 356)` and `JSON API(JSR 353)` but **NOT** the `Batch API`.

If you want to use Java Batch API with weblogic, you need to use **weblogic** **12.2.1** version.